# Unable to embed Webmail Login page

Tags: internal-server-error

I'm trying to embed the 'Web Login' page in one of the pages of my website. However, there's an error saying [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) refused to connect. I suspected that this is due to server misconfiguration or DNS issues. But I'm not too sure if these are the actual causes.[image]

Comment: Does your webmail address work fine individually? How do you want to show it on your website? (iframe, or something) We need more elaboration about your situation.

Comment: What's "Web Login"? What plugin/theme provides it? (Or is this a non-WordPress question? It's hard to tell from what you've provided.) If it *is* a plugin or a theme, you'll need to ask their support team.

Comment: Hello and welcome to WordPress Development SE. If your problem is a server misconfiguration or DNS it might belong on a different SE. As it stands, your question could use some more details. Consider editing it to add clarity and important details.